# php add multiple input fields to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="myForm" method="post" action="add-data.php"> 
        <input type="submit">
        <input type="text" name="pollquestion"> 
        <input type="text" name="polloption1"> 
        <input type="text" name="polloption2"> 
</form> 
<a href="javascript:addOption();">Add option</a> 

<script> 
        var optionNumber = 3;
        function addOption() { 
                var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); 
                var newOption = document.createElement("input"); 
                newOption.name = "polloption"+optionNumber+""; // poll[optionX]
                newOption.type = "text";
                theForm.appendChild(newOption); 
                optionNumber++;
        } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If i add more inputs i will have something like this:

```
<input name="pollquestion" type="text">
<input name="polloption1" type="text">
<input name="polloption2" type="text">
<input name="polloption3" type="text">
<input name="polloption4" type="text">
<input name="polloption5" type="text">
<input name="polloption6" type="text">
```

The php code is something like this:

```
$qu = $_POST['pollquestion'];
$op1 = $_POST['polloption1'];
$op2 = $_POST['polloption2'];
$query = "INSERT into `".$db_table."` (question, option1, option2) VALUES ('" . $qu . "','" . $op1 . "','" . $op2 . "')";
```

How can i add this data to mysql for every added row? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way of many...

```
$query = "INSERT into `$db_table` SET `question` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pollquestion'])."'";

foreach (range(1,6) as $idx) {
   if (!empty($_POST['polloption'.$idx])) {
      $query .= ", `option$idx` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['polloption'.$idx])."'";
   }
}
```

of course the mysql_real_escape_string is important to avoid http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know how many options you're submitting so add another constant input to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="numOptions" name="numOptions"/>
```

In the `addOption()` function update its value (before incrementing `optionNumber`):

```
document.getElementById( "numOptions" ).value = optionNumber;
```

On the server side you need to create your query dynamically like so:

```
$options = array();
$values  = array();
$numOptions = intval( $_POST[ "numOptions" ] );

for ( $i = 1; $i <= $numOptions; $i++ )
{
    $options[] = "option$i";
    $values [] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST[ "polloption$i" ] ) . "'";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO $db_table(" . implode( ',', $options ) . ") VALUES( '" .
         implode( ',', $values );
```

Please mind the escaping of the received strings! very important to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input name="title" type="text">
<input name="descr" type="text">

<input name="question[1]" type="text">
<input name="option[1][1]" type="text">
<input name="option[1][2]" type="text">
<input name="option[1][3]" type="text">
<input name="right[1]" type="radio" value=1>
<input name="right[1]" type="radio" value=2>
<input name="right[1]" type="radio" value=3>

<input name="question[2]" type="text">
<input name="option[2][1]" type="text">
<input name="option[2][2]" type="text">
<input name="option[2][3]" type="text">
<input name="right[2]" type="radio" value=1>
<input name="right[2]" type="radio" value=2>
<input name="right[2]" type="radio" value=3>
```

PHP

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])
$descr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descr'])
$query = "INSERT into `polls` (title,descr) VALUES ('$title', '$descr')";
$id    = $db->query($query);

foreach ($_POST['question'] as $num => $q) {
  $q    = mysql_real_escape_string($q)
  $query = "INSERT into `poll questions` (poll,question) VALUES ($id,'$q')";
  $db->query($query);
  foreach ($_POST['option'][$num] as $i => $opt) {
    $right = ($_POST['right'][$num]) == $i)?1:0;
    $opt   = mysql_real_escape_string($opt)
    $num   = intval($num);
    $query = "INSERT into `poll options` (poll,num,option,right) 
             VALUES ($id,$num,'$opt',$right)";
  }
}
```

Comment: it only ads data into the polls table and this if i remove the foreach {} statement

Comment: i need it for a school project and i`m beginner to php so i don`t know much

Comment: Well, if you want to learn something, you are most heartily welcome, feel free to ask particular questions regarding this code. If you don't know what to ask, if it's way above your understanding, if you understand not a single line from it, you need to learn the basics before trying something such complex. If you want just a working code which you can use with no efforts, you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate $_POST, matching keys with regular patterns, something like that:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    preg_match('/(\w+)(\d+)/Uis', $key, $m);
    if($m[1] == 'polloption') {
        // concatenate new values to your query
    }
}
```

Remembering relational databases, you have fixed number of attributes in your table. So you should add *fixed* number of options.